# Error In Phone Auth Firebase after add Play Integrity

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-play-integrity-api

I added SHA-1 and SHA-256 and it still isn't working. After pressing register, it goes to ReCAPTCHA, but the browser is not loading and this error appears.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBdVc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEVE9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlOxD.png)

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)